# oracle 12c listagg using concatenated field values

Tags: sql, oracle

Using NVL2 to concatenate two fields, the following returns correct data.

```
 select mi2.item_id,
     nvl2(mipp2.serial_number, mipp2.serial_number||'-', null)
     ||nvl2(prod2.code, '' ||prod2.code, null) as green_code
           from store_item mi2
           join store_item_products mipp2
             on mi2.store_item_id = mipp2.store_item_id
           join product prod2 
             on mipp2.product_id = prod2.id
```

What I now need to do is use the green_code data, all within one statement, within a listagg function to gather multiple green_code values within single item_Id values

everything I have tried is returning piles of 'NULL' values and not properly listing the concatenated green_code values.

There are just under fifty additional fields, from these same and eight additional tables,  that need to be returned by the single SQL statement (into a view), so I am trying to stay away from having to list all fields into the group by statement.

Any help with the syntax to gather the above listed concatenated field (green_code) into a listagg function within single item_Id values will be greatly appreciated....

Comment: `LISTAGG(all_that_mess, ', ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY NULL)` If this doesnt work use an outer query to do it,it might be that the order of evaluation of an expression in a function is  wobbly.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I am not able to get your suggestion to produce any results.  The issue is compounded because either of the fields to be concatenated can potentially be null and they come from two different tables and to join those two tables another table must be between them since the two base tables have no direct relationship.  As stated, my code is concatenating them properly ( i think) but when I try to listagg them as a unit as green_code with the item_Id  I cannot get any results that make sense.  It is further complicated by the necessary addition of all the other fields.

Comment: Try to recreate the issue on sqlfiddle

Comment: This gets me closer ahtn anything I have tried, and I have tried doZens opf assorted syntax arrangements.

Comment: {select t.store_item_id,
                   listagg(green_code, ',' )  within group(order by t.store_item_id) as green_code
        from               
    (select mi2.store_item_id,
         nvl2(mipp2.serial_number, mipp2.serial_number||'-', null)
         ||nvl2(prod2.code, '' ||prod2.code, null) as green_code
               from ml_store_item mi2
               join ml_store_item_products mipp2
                 on mi2.store_item_id = mipp2.store_item_id
               join product prod2 
                 on mipp2.product_id = prod2.id) t;}

Answer (score 0):

I may not be correct because what you need to fulfill is not clear. But using a sub query is all what you need it seems. Syntax may be wrong but hope you can get the idea.
e.g. :

```
SELECT item_id, listagg(green_code, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY green_code) as green_code_list 
FROM (select mi2.item_id item_id,
     nvl2(mipp2.serial_number, mipp2.serial_number||'-', null)
     ||nvl2(prod2.code, '' ||prod2.code, null) as green_code
           from store_item mi2
           join store_item_products mipp2
             on mi2.store_item_id = mipp2.store_item_id
           join product prod2 
             on mipp2.product_id = prod2.id )
GROUP BY item_id;
```